# How to convert date field to this format 2018 / 01

Tags: date, sas, format, radix

I have one date field in my table as char `"01jan2017"`,

I want to convert the date field to this format **`"2018 / 01"`** and there should be space between forward slash.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try ? Did you look at the SAS Format help documentation "Dictionary of Formats" ? Will the consumer be happy with YYMMS output ?

Comment: @ASH Thanks for your earlier comment.  Please find my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're looking for is just for display then here is a character conversion

> ```
> data r;
>   date = '01jan2017'd;
>   date1 = compbl(put(year(date),best.)|| " / "||put(month(date),z2.));
> run;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There are three key steps you need to do:

```
catx(' / ',year(input(date_char,date9.)),put(month(input(date_char,date9.)),z2.));
```

1. Convert the date to `date9.` format in order to extract the year and month,
2. Use the `z2.` format for the month to get the leading Zero,
3. Use `Catx()` to concatinate the year , month & ' / '.

Full Code:

```
data want;
date_char="01jan2017";
dateYYMM=catx(' / ',year(input(date_char,date9.)),put(month(input(date_char,date9.)),z2.));
run;
```

Output:

```
 date_char=01jan2017 dateYYMM=2017 / 01
```